# Android studio: Evitar el centrado de controles dentro de un LinearLayout(Horizontal) cuando hay más de uno

Tags: android-studio, xml, android-layout, programación-móvil

Tengo este escenario

[image: Linear layout(horizontal) con dos controles (Textview y Multiline Text)]

Como pueden ver el control `TextView` con texto *Description* está centrado verticalmente con respecto al control `Multiline Text`. Esto ocurre de forma automática cuando añado el segundo control.

Mi intención es evitarlo, de manera que ***Description* quedara en la zona marcada en rojo** (`Multiline Text` permanecería inmóvil).

[image: LinearLayout(Horizontal): donde debería quedar el <code>TextView</code>]

Extiendanse todo lo que quieran en su respuesta, soy nuevo en Android Studio y este es mi primer trabajo con *Layouts*. Si consideran que otro tipo de layout sería mejor, por favor haganmelo saber.

Answer (score 0):

Acá le dejo el código para la vista que busca.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.09">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Descripción"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/multitext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/multi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="Esto es una descripción de lo que sucede..."
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Saludos.